# Electric field in Cylinder

Tags: mathematical-physics, electromagnetism

I have two infinitely long cylinders having surface charge density p=a,b (b>a). 
How do I find the electric fields at all points? 
Should I use Gauss law? If so, how will I need to use surface integral?

[My work so far](https://i.stack.imgur.com/77Wlu.jpg)

Comment: What work have you done so far?

Comment: I have attached my work. Please check above. @Zach